# Processbuilder-opening java script in linux

Tags: java, jar, processbuilder

Back again, this time with a java question. I was told how to get Processbuilder to run nonnative scripts (calling the program that would run the script), but I've been trying to run a java script and have run into a couple problems. First off, should I use a .class or .jar? both of these can be run but I'm not sure which one of them will work better. And then how do I execute them correctly? I've tried calling java (/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java) and then giving the filepath to the class file, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: My recollection from ages ago was that `.jar` was the format of choice if you've got two or more classes. Just about every useful program does, so use `.jar`. Even if you don't have two classes yet, chances are good that you will :) so you might as well not bother your users with a change in how to start your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with sarnold in terms of the .jar question.  In terms of executing code using ProcessBuilder, you can execute a .jar file as long as this file contains a `main()` method, and has the `Main-Class` manifest header, which can be generated when the .jar is created.  Once you have the .jar created, you'd use a command like this to run the .jar:

`java -jar jar_file_name_here.jar`

If you have multiple main classes and you want to run a specific one, you could use a command like this:

`java -jar jar_name.jar com.main.class.package.path.here.SomeClassName`

Are you trying to execute someone elses .jar, or is it one of your own that you just want to be executed inside a script?  Why are you using a script, out of curiosity?

Comment: I'm actually doing a science project, and I'm utilizing a main java program to run a group of scripts from other languages-hence the processbuilder. The java script has just one class, by the way.

Also, processbuilder requires a program and then the script. I'd prefer to be able to call processbuilder on all of my scripts for consistency's sake. Sadly, that means I can't use flags when calling programs.

Comment: you could always use a system scripting language to run the processes too.  if your on Linux, you could always write a batch script to do the same thing, and you can re-route the output from the programs if you see fit.  I know that you can do the same in Java, it just seems like it might be more straightforward if you did it the scripting way...

Comment: haha, yeah, that probably would be easier. Sadly, since this a school project I have to use Java for the main program.

what would I do to generate the main_class on creation of the .jar?

Comment: well, the whole Main-Class/manifest info really helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You either need -jar and the pathname of a jar that has a manifest that names your main class, or -cp with the pathname of a directory that has your classes in it in the standard layout, or -cp with the pathname of a jar followed by the name of the class with a main.

```
java -jar I_AM_A_JAR_WITH_A_MANIFEST.jar

java -cp I_AM_JAR_1.jar:I_AM_JAR2.jar... this.is.my.FooClass

java -cp dir_path1:dir_path2:dir_path3 this.is.my.FooClass
```

where the 'dir_pathN' is a dir with standard class hierarchy.